# remix-auth-socials - http 400 {"message": "Missing state on session."} on production, on localhost its working

Tags: remix.run

I am trying to make work Google auth on my first remix.run js FW via https://www.npmjs.com/package/remix-auth-socials

On localhost, it works nicely, however on production server its crashing on redirect callback:

- URL: [my correct redirect URI]
- response http code: 400 Bad request
- response body: {message: "Missing state on session."}

My configuration is based on readme in [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remix-auth-socials):

```
// ~/services/session.server
export const sessionStorage = createCookieSessionStorage({
    cookie: {
        ...
        secure: true
    },
});

...
```

I found in FW code that its crashing with this message if it fails to read session from remix sessionStorage.

**Does anybody knows what can cause this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes

```
Secure Optional
Indicates that the cookie is sent to the server only when a request is made with the https: scheme (except on localhost), and therefore, is more resistant to man-in-the-middle attacks.
```

This was it, i am not running on https, so solution was to set:

```
cookie.secure: false
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/sergiodxa/remix-auth/discussions/156#discussioncomment-2536785

This is a common issue if you're coming from one of the remix templates where the cookie's maxAge is set to 0 (useful for implementing a 'remember me' feature). However what this means is the browser immediately sees the cookie as stale. Either remove that property or update it to be a longer time frame. I use `maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 30 days`